# Why run this code programmatically in MongoDB is error

Tags: mongodb-query

```
db.runCommand({"group" :{
    "ns" : "keyword_logs",
    "key" : "keyword",
    "initial" : {"keyword" : {}},
    "$reduce" : function (doc , prev) {
        if(doc.keyword != null && prev.keyword != null &&(doc.keyword in prev.keyword)) {
             prev.keyword[doc.keyword]++;
        }
        else {
             prev.keyword[doc.keyword] = 1 ;
        }
     },
     "condition" : {"domain" : 40}
}})
```

this is errorMsg

```
{
"errmsg" : "exception: JavaScript property (name) contains a null char which is not allowed in BSON. {}",
"code" : 16985,
"ok" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gibert Sun , in his help ,we find the error:
This is the code to find the error data

```
db.runCommand({
        "group" :{
            "ns" : "keyword_logs",
            "key" : "keyword",
            "initial" : {"error" : []},
            "$reduce" : function (doc , prev) {
                if (/\u0000/.test(doc.keyword)) prev.error.push(doc);
            },
            "condition" : {"domain" : 10}
        }
    })
```

this is the new code for the search

```
db.runCommand({
    "group" :{
        "ns" : "keyword_logs",
        "key" : "keyword",
        "initial" : {"keyword" : {}},
        "$reduce" : function (doc , prev) {
            if (/\u0000/.test(doc.keyword)) return;
            var kw = doc.keyword;
            if(kw in prev.keyword){
                prev.keyword[doc.keyword]++;
            }else{
                prev.keyword[doc.keyword] = 1 ;
            }
        },
        "condition" : {"domain" : 10}
    }
})
```